# Blueprism Issue with Finding File

Tags: blueprism

I have a process which zips a file and emails it on. The process works most of the time. However, every so often I get an error message similar to the below.

ERROR: System Exception : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Could not find a part of the path 'T:\Path\Folder\File.zip'.

This is strange as it is able to find the original excel file, then zip it. 
If I use the location from the error message I am able to find the file.

Is there an issue with the time it takes for the machine to find the file? Is this a bug?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Do you have any special characters in the path you're trying to access?

Comment: Not sure about your situation, but I've seen something similar when some users were using a process from thin clients. I had to change the folder-path to include the full domain address e.g. \\domain(w_whatever)\T:\Path\Folder\File.zip to get it to work...don't ask me why..! :)

Comment: Hey, can you explain how you generate the zip file? The issue may come from there

Comment: I have no special characters in the file path, It works more often then not Badda_Bing do you think that would sound like your issue? The file is generated using Winzip

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that the file is getting zipped and you are trying to pick it up for sending mail, So solution Can be

1. Give some wait of 1 or 2 sec after zipping (as it may require some time for finishing work Not sure.)
2. While sending mail please ensure the file exists at location
3. If Point 2 is true, send the email with attachment
4. If point 2 is false, Raise the error to main process: "Zipped file not found"

After the zipping the files, if not created/zipped retry for 3 time or you can raise the error "Error: while zipping the files".

Ensure that zip file name should not contain any special character like ` , :

By doing so, we can able to find where the exact error is, whether is is on zipping code or file existence.